# Как получить текущее время с помощью функции NOW в timestamp witchout time zone без миллисекунд?

Tags: sql, postgresql, время, функции

Записываю текущее время в поле с типом `timestamp witchout time zone` вот таким способом:

`SELECT NOW();`

Проблема в том что выводятся миллисекунды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А они не нужны.

Вопрос как получить `timestamp witchout time zone` без миллисекунд? нужно получит вот такой формат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

надо подрезать последнюю секунду:

```
SELECT date_trunc('seconds', now()::timestamp);
```